# Why repository.delete( entity_with_id_null) kicks off SQL INSERT + DELETE

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Why repository.delete( entity_With_Null_Id) kicks off SQL INSERT + DELETE

Using a repository and trying to delete an Entity with id==null kicks off 2 unnecessary SQL orders and no exception !

```
    @Test
    public void removeWithIdNull() {

        // ARRANGE
        Info infoWithIdNull = new Info("entity with id null");
        List<Info> listA = infoRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(listA, hasSize(0));

        // ACT
        infoRepository.delete(infoWithIdNull);

        // ASSERT
        List<Info> listResult = infoRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(listResult, hasSize(0));

    }
```

This generates the following SQLs :
An INSERT and then a DELETE =>

```
    DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - insert into info (message, version, id) values (?, ?, ?)
    TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [entity with id null] 
    TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0] 
    TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [10] 

    DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - delete from info where id=? and version=? 
    TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [10]
    TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
```

this really annoys me, why does Spring-Data-JPA does not check that the entity exists before deleting it, instead of doing a merge() ..

Code in Data-JPA SimpleJpaRepository which explains this behaviour:

```
    @Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {

        Assert.notNull(entity, "The entity must not be null!");
        em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
    }
```

this code seems over-simplified to me.
What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

lets analyze the code

```
    em.remove(em.contains(entity) ? entity : em.merge(entity));
```

you ask if `em` contains the entity then `remove` it, else `merge` it then `remove` it,
the `merge` operation produce `insert` statement

Comment: this is NOT my code but spring-data-jpa code. I understand perfectly what this code does. I just don't agree with it. Ans so am asking for support. In the end I will probably create a JIRA issue ...

Comment: @GauthierPeel, i am sorry, i missed this point, it not your code

Answer (score 0):

I ended up posting on JIRA and the problem is now FIXED in version spring-data-jpa 2.2.
It was considered a real problem.
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1535

Comment: The problem is now solved (1535) and solution is implemented in Spring-Data-JPA-2.2.0 RC3 at the moment

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand your problem. You want to delete an entity which is actually not mapped to any DB row.

What do you expect? We are only talking about deletion when the entity is PRESENT in the db, otherwise there is no point to delete it.

IMHO your test is wrong. First you want to persist the entity which you wanna delete.

Comment: I expect that Spring Data Repository would detect that kind of problem and not generate weird SQL ...

Comment: Then you expect the wrong thing. Spring Data is not a silver bullet and you should use it properly. You have to take care of your entities, not Spring Data.

Comment: it would be easy to fix ... That is what I did it myself in custom Repository abstract implementation. And since it is easy and foolproof, I don't know why spring fwk does not do it.

Comment: If you just don't agree with it, then fill a ticket for them.